# Trying to use python to find if a column contains text with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the code basically working however when I add an additional word to look for regex returns false for all rows. I have verified that some of the columns contain those key words.

```
df["MED"] = df['Description'].str.contains('x|y', regex=False, case=False)
```

Comment: You say regex returns false for all rows, but have `regex=False`. Meaning it's searching for cells which contain exactly the letters `"x|y"` is that what you're trying to do? Or did you mean to create a regular expression looking for _either_ x or y?

Comment: @HenryEcker the latter.

Comment: Then you should just have `regex=True` not `False`